# Will Eladrin Boots and Gloves of Dimensional Repulsion enhance teleports created by Walk Among the Fey?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation, bard

Walk Among the Fey says that "Whenever you use a power that slides a creature, you can teleport that creature an equal number of squares instead.  Where you teleport the creature remains subject to any restrictions on the original slide."

There are several magic items that seem like they'd allow the teleport distance to be increased:

- Eladrin Boots add 2 squares to the distance of "any teleport you make"
- Gloves of Dimensional Repulsion add 2 squares to the distance of "teleport powers" used on creatures other than yourself

So, I guess there are 3 questions here:

1. Does "any teleport you make" only apply to teleporting yourself, or can it apply to teleporting others as well?
2. Alternately, if I use a power that slides a target, and I've got Walk Among the Fey, does it become a "teleport power" ?
3. ...Or is this all moot because of the "restrictions on the original slide" bit?  (I'm pretty sure a restriction like "target must wind up adjacent to you" would carry over, but how about just "you may slide the target up to K spaces"?)

Answer (score 3):

**Neither of the two items work**

Eladrin Boots would not work as it stipulates any teleport the character makes, restricting its bonus to teleportation of the PC.

Gloves of Dimensional Repulsion is trickier because its written poorly (a lot of items in the Adventurers Vault fail to live up to the rest of 4e in terms of using the accepted terms). The phrase "When you use a teleport power on a target other than yourself" really is referring to nothing because there is no designation of "teleport power" in 4e. However Powers have keywords and **teleportation** is one of them, so what I believe they are trying to say is whenever you use a power with the **teleportation** keyword you can teleport the target 2 additional squares.

**No, hitting a target with a power that slides them, triggering *Walk with Fey* is not the same as a "teleport power"**

As I said above teleport power isn't anything in 4e, but a power with the **teleportion** keyword is.  Since *Walk Among the Fey* changes the movement from slide to teleport, but does not add the **teleportation** keyword to the power it would not trigger Gloves of Dimension Repulsion.

**It's not moot, just not the free pass you thought it might turn out to be and more of a utility/flavor feat vs. a strong optimization choice**

Depending on the power in question their may be absolutely no restrictions. Walk Among the Fey could trigger on any action that causes an enemy to slide  so you're just going to have to work with the power in question. Teleporting any enemy would let you move them through other characters, but that is about the only mechanical benefit I can ascribe to it.

Comment: Being teleportation, it should also allow you to slide them through terrain that would otherwise be problematic as well... such as walls.

Comment: Walls yes, but dangerous or hindering terrain still has the exact same limitations (they get to make a save roll against going in) regardless of how they get there.

Comment: Really? That doesn't make any sense... if you teleport through a square how can you be affected by it?

Comment: Sorry, difficult terrain is fine, dangerous/hindering terrain aka a fall or damaging terrain they get to make a save to catch oneself under the forced movement rules.

Comment: The keyword is 'Teleportation', not 'Teleport'. Also, teleportation is not forced movement. Rules Compendium pg 200: A creature can be moved in other ways, such as through teleportation, but only pulls, pushes, and slides are technically forced movement.

Comment: Changing a slide into a teleport in order to move the target through characters is somewhat redundant. Sliding a target allows the character to control the target's movement. So, unless there are no open squares to either side of the character you want to slide the target through, teleporting them instead gives you no additional benefit.

Comment: I think this answer takes a very narrow view on these rule interactions and I'd need to be convinced via either errata or FAQ (and the 4e FAQ sometimes contradicts rules so I'd still be skeptical with a source from it). Changing a slide to a teleport for a feat is poor utility except under two circumstances: 1) your campaign takes place entirely in unbreakable glass dungeons or 2) you can take some of the teleportation optimizations. Since the rules are very open to interpretation about #2, I don't see any reason to needlessly restrict Walk Among the Fey from interacting with other options.

Answer (score 3):

Joshua Aslan Smith makes a number of completely reasonable assumptions in his answer, but I think it's important note that they are in fact assumptions.

### Any Teleport You Make

I'm not inclined to assume this means that you are the one that must teleport. That would be totally reasonable, but I can't say for sure that it's the case. I mean, if I teleport somebody across the room, then that was a teleport, and I made it.

Maybe Smith has a rules reference from which he drew his conclusion, but he didn't say what it is and I don't know about it.

I would discuss the interpretation of this sentence with my DM and make sure that everyone is on the same page before trying to use these boots.

### What is a Teleport Power

Once again, it is completely reasonable to assume that Wizards *intended* the Gloves of Dimensional Repulsion to affect powers with the Teleportation keyword, but we don't actually know that for sure. This assumption would be consistent with the way in which most effects determine which powers they interact with: keywords. In this case, Smith is completely correct that Walk with the Fey does not add the Teleportation keyword to powers.

It would also be reasonable to point out that the Adventurer's Vault has a 9 page errata document available on Wizards' site, and nowhere in there will you find a word about these gloves. If they're going to take the time to add keywords to powers, you would think they would also make any changes to effect text that interacts with keywords. In this case, I would say a 'teleport' power is any power which teleports, which would be true of any slide power while wearing these gloves.

Either way, it's an assumption. So, once again, discuss this item with your DM to make sure you're on the same page about how it works.

### Restrictions? What?

I believe that they're referring to restrictions on the destination, since they specifically say "*Where* you teleport the creature remains subject...", but maybe not. Smith seems to think that this would include generalized restrictions, even going so far as to suggest that a creature would get a saving throw for being teleported across dangerous terrain.

If my understanding is correct, then at first blush the clause seems redundant. They already say "an equal number of squares", however the number of squares is not always the only restriction. Sometimes they have to end adjacent to you, as you pointed out, or something along those lines. The "up to K spaces" restriction you asked about is covered by the "equal number of squares" clause. If you can slide the target up to 5 squares, then you can teleport them 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 squares.

So, you could teleport through enemy spaces, through blocking terrain, past dangerous terrain, and so on, just so long as the final destination square meets any restrictions on the slide's destination square.